# How should i handle a product signup through an iPhone app?

Tags: php, iphone, registration, url-parameters

I have an iOS app which reads out a serial number from a hardware through bluetooth or wifi. I also have a website where users can register to see which product they own. (the problem is a little more complex, i just wanted to simplify things).

When they start using the iOS app, it will ask if they want to register the product on my website. In this case, the iPhone app redirects the user to my signup(or login) page and the serial number is simply a get parameter in my url(for example: *www.samplesite.com?signup?sn=0100013*) and of course the sn value will be stored in the database.

Is there a way to hide this value from the url, or make things safer, so people can't register random serial numbers through the system? My main issue is that the serial number is not unique, it just simply starts from 0 and increased one by one.

Encrypting the SN with a fixed key which stored on my website and inside the app is a solution?

Answer (score 0):

"Encrypting the SN with a fixed key which stored on my website and inside the app is a solution?"

This could be a possible solution.

Here is another solution:

1. Make sure that every user has a unique API_KEY so that you can track
   users of your iPhone application.
2. While making the request to your
   web server(like a web service call), make sure that the page has
   this API_KEY `www.samplesite.com?signup?sn=0100013&api_key=abc123`.
   Based on the API_KEY, make decisions on your web server either to
   store or discard or do whatever with this call.